# Visual Studio Code: move files in two columns simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two files, and they are similar in terms of the number of lines. I open them in two columns.  When I scroll down in one column, I hope that the file in another column scrolls down too automatically. How can I do it?

**Update**:
I don't want VSC to compare two files or generate any visual indicators. I just want them to scroll simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Update: from 1.88.0-insider, it's [natively supported](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110#issuecomment-1997823266).

---

You can use the `workbench.files.action.compareFileWith` command to compare the active file with the selected file, then the two files can be scrolled simultaneously.

Also, make sure your `diffEditor.renderSideBySide` setting is `true`, it's to ensure the editors are opened side by side.

But if you don't want to see the diff decorations, there's currently no native way to do this, the corresponding feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33110). In the meantime, you can try the [Sync Scroll](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=dqisme.sync-scroll) extension.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I don't want VSC to compare two files or generate any visual indicators. I just want them to scroll simultaneously. Is that doable?

Comment: @curious1 I've updated my answer, please see above.